# Как выбрать самое маленькое значение из подходящих под условие в ассоциативном массиве?

Tags: javascript, jquery, массивы

Имеется код такого типа:

```
var sell = [
  {"breed": "sosna", "size": "20x100x6000", "cost": 1500},
  {"breed": "sosna", "size": "30x100x6000", "cost": 2500},
  {"breed": "sosna", "size": "40x100x6000", "cost": 3500},
  {"breed": "sosna", "size": "20x100x6000", "cost": 4500},
  {"breed": "sosna", "size": "30x100x6000", "cost": 5500},
  {"breed": "sosna", "size": "40x100x6000", "cost": 6500},  
];

$.each(sell, function (index, value) {
  if (breed.val() == value.breed && size.val() == value.size){
    console.log(value.cost);
  };
});
```

И суть вопроса в том, что код выдает несколько значений "value.cost", а мне нужно только одно, причем самое маленькое. Я уже пробовал что-то такое:

```
console.log(Math.min.apply(Math,value.cost));
```

но не получается. Подскажите что же мне делать пожалуйста!

Comment: `let itemWithMinCost = sell.reduce((a, b) => a.cost < b.cost ? a : b);`

Comment: @TheGmafaka в js нет ассоциативных массивов, это массив объектов (индексный).